# Median Absolute Deviation calculation with a condition

Tags: excel

I have coded the Median Absolute Deviation in Excel as:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(ISNUMBER(c10:c14345),ABS(c10:c14345-MEDIAN(c10:c14345))))
```

This formula works fine on a range of numbers (in this case c10:c14345).

I would like to calculate the formula on a subset of the observations using an IF statement to specify the condition (in my case what country the data is coming from in column D). My formula is:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(DATA!$D$10:$D$14345=$A308,ABS(DATA!C$10:C$14345-MEDIAN(DATA!C$10:C$14345))))
```

which works well if all the cells contain numeric data. However, in some cases there are missing values and the formula gives an error `#Value!`.

How can I incorporate the ISNUMBER  condition into the formula?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using ISNUMBER like this:-

```
=MEDIAN(IF((Data!$D$10:$D$14345=$A308)*ISNUMBER(Data!C$10:C$14345),ABS(Data!C$10:C$14345-MEDIAN(Data!C$10:C$14345))))
```

to make sure that it excludes blanks and text values.

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Like your formula, it does the absolute differences from the median of the whole dataset, which I assume is what you want.

Note that the '*' is a way of putting an AND condition in an array formula. It has the effect of coercing the two logical conditions either side of it from true/false to 1/0, then multiplying them together so that if either are false you get a zero result and the test in the IF statement fails.

Comment: This works perfectly. Does the * denote multiplication or some other meaning in this context? Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's great. I will put a note in the answer to say that although the '*' does denote multiplication, it is really just a convenient way of putting an 'AND' condition in an array formula.